# How can I set up automatic wallpaper changing on the lock screen in Variety?

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen, desktop-background

How can I set up automatic wallpaper changing on the lock screen using the wallpaper changer program Variety?  Ubuntu 18.04 DE Gnome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the preferences->customize settings of Variety which may do what you are trying to do.  The catch is that this works only with `lightDM`, so you will need  to make sure that `LightDM` is installed and active:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and then you will need to reboot...

Variety indicates that the `lightDM` interface is 'touchy', and offers some suggestions as to what to do if it does not work:  https://answers.launchpad.net/variety/+faq/2271

Please be aware that this dates back to 2013, and may not work at all with current versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Charles Green, thank you for your answer. It's okay if I replace gdm for lightdm ?

Comment: You can switch back and forth between gdm3 and lightdm, by running `sudo dpkg-recondifgure lightdm`, and rebooting.  Its a painlessish process

Comment: Does not work. By the way thank you for trying to help.